# Data merge into one sheet

Tags: excel

I have a multiple worsheets with commodity selling data which were cropped in that farm.
Every day farmers fill that column for each farm and I want to merge it to one Total worksheet.

For example we have farm in new york and march 12th farmer sold 500 tones of corn at that farm.(sheet name is New York Farm)
We have another farm in Los Angeles and again on march 12th farmer sold 700 tones of corn (sheet name is Los Angeles Farm)

I want this data to show up on the mail sheet called total. The trick is if there is no data the Total will be empty.

I have a total of 10 farm and need on Total sheet create everytime a new column if some of the commodity was sold.

I can not use macro or any VBA coding. Is there any way or combination of function to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share how your sheet looks and what your desired output would look like in the sheet where this data is combined. Doing this outside of VBA is going to be tricky.

Comment: This is a project with a software spec but no original effort.

Comment: Why can't you use macro or VBA? Really don't think you can do what you want without code. Creating new column for new data is very poor database design. Why don't you use Access database?